# What has the Chinese government done as a response to US sanctions on its tech sector?

Tags: united-states, china, trade, sanctions

From Trump to Biden, many Chinese **tech** companies have either gone out of business or sustained significant financial damage because of US security-related sanctions (e.g., Huawei, etc.).

What has the Chinese government done in this regard? Did they retaliate? Did the Chinese government bail those companies out? Explain how that happened.

Answer (score 3):

[Nikkei Asia - *China softens blow of U.S. sanctions on military companies* - KENJI KAWASE, Nikkei Asia chief business news correspondent - June 2, 2022 11:38 JST](https://asia.nikkei.com/Politics/International-relations/US-China-tensions/China-softens-blow-of-U.S.-sanctions-on-military-companies)

> HONG KONG -- With all U.S. citizens and entities forbidden from investing China's military-industrial companies by Friday, Beijing has mobilized state funds and its capital market to cushion the potential fallout.

With regards to the question "How did they retaliate?": it is worth noting that the effect of sanctions is not just one-way. American companies may also experience fallout!

[Brookings.edu - *Economic Sanctions: Too Much of a Bad Thing* - Richard N. Haass - Monday, June 1, 1998](https://www.brookings.edu/research/economic-sanctions-too-much-of-a-bad-thing/)